# URLSubmit handling of query parameters

Tags: bugs, syntax, web-access

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

> [CASE:4007421] confirmed

---

```
myApi = CloudDeploy@APIFunction[{"i" -> "Real"}, #i &];
```

Why does the first call fail?

```
URLSubmit[myApi, {"i" -> RandomReal[]}
 , HandlerFunctions -> <|"BodyReceived" -> Print|>
 ]
```

> ```
> <|Body->{{
>     "Success": false,
>     "Failure": "The API could not be evaluated because there is no input for fields: \"i\".",
>     "Fields": {
>         "i": {
>             "AllowedExtensions": [
>                 "json"
>             ],
>             "AutoSubmitting": false,
>             "CodeLanguage": "Automatic",
>             "Default": null,
>             "Enabled": true,
>             "Failure": "This field is required.",
>             "Help": null,
>             "Hidden": false,
>             "Hint": null,
>             "Input": null,
>             "Interpreter": "Real",
>             "Label": "i",
>             "Required": true,
>             "Type": "Element"
>         }
>     }
> }}|>
> ```

```
URLSubmit[HTTPRequest[First@myApi, <|"Query" -> {"i" -> RandomReal[]}|>]
 , HandlerFunctions -> <|"BodyReceived" -> Print|>
 ]
```

> ```
> <|Body->{0.990822}|>
> ```

Comment: Honestly I think so many of these URL and HTTP handling bugs can be traced to the inconsistencies in having 80000000 different implementations rather than a single function with `Options`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is confirmed so in order to take it of the unanswered stack I will put a workaround as an answer:

```
URLSubmit[
  HTTPRequest[First @ myApi, <|"Query" -> {"i" -> RandomReal[]}|>]
, HandlerFunctions -> <|"BodyReceived" -> Print|>
]
```